# Set and check token 'Bearer xxxxx' in body instead header

Tags: laravel, jwt, authorization, bearer-token

I'm using Laravel and use Tymon\JWTAuth for authentication.
As we know, when user login successfully, we will set the token to the header and when user call other api, Laravel will check it in header: "Authorization: Bearer xxxxx" by default
My spec is: in body I will pass the token with param: "token: Bearer xxxx", so I wonder if I could check the token in body and how to do this. It is my current spec and could not be changed to move to header, please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can create a middleware to check the `Authorization` property inside your request body, see [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#defining-middleware) here. Inside that middleware, you can check whether the token sent is valid or not.